# Issue with sqoop import from mysql to hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop

I am trying to import data from mysql to hbase using sqoop:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://<hostname>:3306/test --username USERNAME -P --table testtable --direct --hbase-table testtable --column-family info --hbase-row-key id --hbase-create-table
```

The process runs smoothly, without any error, but the data goes to hdfs and **not** to hbase.

Here is my setup:

HBase and Hadoop is installed in distributed mode in my three server cluster. Namenode and HBase Master being one one server. Datanodes and Region server lies in two other servers. Sqoop is installed in NameNode server only.
I am using Hadoop version 0.20.2-cdh3u3, hbase version 0.90.6-cdh3u4 and sqoop version 1.3.0-cdh3u3.

Any suggestions where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sqoop's direct connectors usually do not support HBase and this is definitely the case for MySQL direct connector. You should drop the --direct option if you need import data into HBase.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jarek, it solved the issue.
The table is being created in HBase, however I'm getting the below error:
`13/04/23 11:53:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201304231148_0003
13/04/23 11:53:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/04/23 11:53:40 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201304231148_0003_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: testtable : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Got it working... Need to set JAVA_HOME path correctly in hadoop-env.sh file

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of importing data from Mysql to HBase
http://souravgulati.webs.com/apps/forums/topics/show/8680714-sqoop-import-data-from-mysql-to-hbase